# Terminated postgres.exe processes caused by .NET application

Tags: .net, windows, postgresql

I have postgres database running on a windows server. The windows resource monitor tells me that I have maybe a dozen `postgres.exe` processes running normally, and maybe 50-60 processes with a 'terminated' status.

I have a `.NET` application that seems to be causing these processes. When I switch it off the terminated processes die off, when I switch it on they come back again. The application seems to be working normally, it does what it's supposed to do with no obvious sign of errors. However, these terminated processes all seem to be using a large bite of the available CPU (according to resource monitor)

The application only uses a single database connection, so what might be causing all these processes and what might be causing their termination? would a transaction experiencing a locking-conflict result in a terminated process? what about a query that times-out? Or maybe all these processes are an internal postgres thing not directly related to the application?

Update -
With the `.NET` application off, I have checked the postgres logfile (no errors) and checked windows resource monitor (no terminated examples of postgres.exe). Then I restart the application and wait a few minutes. Several dozen 'terminated' processes have appeared on the resource monitor, no new errors in the postgres logfile (and the `.NET` application is working with no logged errors). The database is currently configured with the default *postgres.conf* settings (v13)

Comment: Is there anything strange in your PostgreSQL log? It is normal for the backend process to terminate when you close the database connection. Perhaps you need a connection pool.

Comment: Since you chose not to update this question, but [ask the question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66599113/6464308), would you please at least close this one?

Comment: @Laurenz - I felt that the other question I asked - how to write a powershell to monitor terminated processes - was sufficiently different to justify a different question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.