# Monitoring terminated windows processes

Tags: windows, postgresql, performance, powershell

Windows resource manager tell me I have dozens of `postgres.exe` processes of which about 80% have a status of `terminated`.

I'm trying to use powershell to count exactly how many I have at any one moment. This little script will count all those running normally at any one moment, how can I modify to list all those `terminated` ones?

```
$wait=1; 
$procname="postgres" ; 
do {$c = (get-process $procname | measure).count ;
"Number of {0} processes: {1}" -f $procname, $c;
start-sleep -sec $wait} until ($false)
```

SOLVED (partially) - The resource manager lists terminated processes for maybe 20 seconds (or more) after the process has died. Whereas `get-process()` retrieves the status of the processes at the nano-second the command is executed.

This variation on the original seem to be an improvement

```
$wait=50; 
$procname="postgres" ; 
do {$c = (get-process $procname |where {$_.hasexited -eq $true }| measure).count ;
"Number of {0} processes: {1}" -f $procname, $c;
start-sleep -Milliseconds $wait} until ($false)
```

frequency increased to 20Hz, and the use of `{$_.hasexited -eq $true }` to list completed processes.

Comment: Seems like those "exited processes" are zombies. Could it be that you open and close lots of database connections? Then you need a connection pool.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - thanks, but as far as I can tell only ONE database connection is being explicitly opened, unless there's some subtle behind-the-scenes opening/closing of connections that I can't spot.

Comment: PostgreSQL processes only terminate 1) when you shutdown the server 2) when a client disconnects 3) when a parallel query finishes.